# DRM support for BlueStacks

Tags: android-emulator, video-streaming, drm, bluestacks

Is there any way one can get [DRM(Digital Right Management)](https://www.tunefab.com/tutorials/drm-protected-streams-are-not-supported.html) support for online streaming in [Bluestacks](https://www.bluestacks.com)? Or Is there any other emulator which can support this?

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

DRM support on a mobile device is typically built into the device or OS now and can be subtly different per device - for example two seemingly comparable high end smart phones may have different DRM security levels, meaning one can receive HD or 4K content from a particular service while the other may be restricted to lower resolutions.

For your case, most high end Android phones will support the highest level of Widevine DRM, while most Windows and MAC's may not so you may find that even if Bluestacks can leverage a native DRM on your device (typically PlayReady on Windows or FairPlay on Mac) you may still not have the stream in the right format to allow you watch it reliably.

More widely, support for DRM content in emulators is sometimes simply not available, or other times actually provided by the underlying emulator platform itself. As this may be completely different to the end device it is not a reliable way to test, so you will often find that DRM video is tested on representative end devices rather than on an emulator, if it is just testing you are aiming for.